# Unable to access store and publisher in API Manager

Tags: wso2

I followed the directions on how to add  BAM to the API manager, but now I get a Null Pointer exception when trying to access the store and publisher where I can not log into either of them.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.<init>(ApiMgtDAO.java:81)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.<init>(AbstractAPIManager.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.<init>(APIConsumerImpl.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.<init>(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:43)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens if you have a syntax issue in the api-manager.xml configuration. Can you double check for a possible issue in api-manager.xml.

Comment: Yep.  I botched the update for the datasource name
`DataSourceName>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</DataSourceName`